# CPU fan stopped working on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: upgrade, fan, 21.10, fancontrol

I am running Ubuntu on an HP Pavilion G6 Notebook PC. My CPU fan stopped working when I upgraded to Ubuntu 21.10 impish indri. What could be the problem?

Comment: cpu fan you mean?

Comment: Yes CPU fan is not working

Comment: My CPU fan stopped working when I installed Ubuntu impish indri

Comment: How do you know it stopped working? Does the laptop overheat?